# How can I remove the {''} in my variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I recently made a command that saves the information into a JSON file. So basically, I have 2 commands, first command sets the global variable, and the second command uses the variables provided to add into the JSON file. And once I tested it, it saves the text as a global variable, and then it saved into the JSON file as `{'test'}`. I don't want the {''}, so is there a way to don't have {''}, only the text `test`?

Script:

```
#global variables
namereg = None
cbreg = None #more
bdreg = None
descreg = None
libreg = None
invreg = None
btreg = None
ssreg = None
slugreg = None

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def namereg(ctx, *, arg):
            global namereg
            namereg = {arg}
            embed = discord.Embed(title='Registed Name.',description=f'Set the name as {arg}',colour=discord.Color.dark_green())
            print(f'{arg}')
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def add(ctx):
        role_names = [role.name for role in ctx.message.author.roles]
        if "Server Moderator" in role_names:
            def write_json(data, filename='bots.json'):
                with open (filename, "w") as f:
                    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

            with open ('bots.json') as json_file:
                data = json.load(json_file)
                temp = data["bots"]
                y = {"name": f"{namereg}"}
                temp.append(y)

            write_json(data)
            embed = discord.Embed(title='Added!',description='Successfully added with the following!',timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,colour=discord.Color.dark_green())
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

If there is a way to not have {''}, please reply to this thread! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you save it as a json, then that format is what it recognizes.  If you want to save it without the ```{""}```, then you save it to a normal file.

Comment: Neither `{'test'}` nor `{"test"}` is valid JSON. If this is what's getting written to your file then there is something very seriously wrong, otherwise you need to edit the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Alright so i don't mean the json file. Basically it when i saved it as a global variable and i used another command to see what is the variable it will show up as `{'test'}` too.

Comment: When you write `{"name": f"{namereg}"}`, in your own words, what is the purpose of the `f'{}'` part? How exactly are you expecting the `global namereg` to get a value? Walk through the steps of that. Also, keep in mind that your function `namereg` will conflict with the variable.

Comment: @kaya3 what appears to be meant is that `"{'test'}"` appears in the JSON as a string value, where simply `"test"` is desired. This happens because the value `{'test'}` (a single-element set containing the string `'test'`) is string-formatted and than json-serialized, rather than `'test'` (just a string).

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing it to a JSON file, the quotes will be added every time as part of JSON syntax. If you just need to write a dictionary to a file (which is also readable), you can write it to a normal .txt file.

Comment: Alright so i don't mean the json file. Basically it when i saved it as a global variable and i used another command to see what is the variable it will show up as {'test'} too.

Comment: Are you reading the variable from the json file again, to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

```
namereg = None

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def namereg(ctx, *, arg):
    global namereg
```

This is broken. Functions at the top level of your code **are** global variables, and are in the same namespace. Give it a different name from the storage variable.

```
    namereg = {arg}
```

This takes the string that came from the user's input, and creates a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) with a single element. That is not what you want. You wanted the input string to be the registered name, so just assign it directly.

```
        y = {"name": f"{namereg}"}
```

I assume you did this fancy formatting because you were getting an error before (because the `json` will not serialize sets by default, because the JSON data format does not have a direct way to represent them). You should have listened to this error message more closely, by questioning why you had data of the invalid type in the first place. The `{}` and `''` in your output come from the string representation of the set that you stringify using the string formatting. The plain string that you want to use does not require any formatting to convert to string, because it is already a string.

Comment: Do you mean that I'll need to make the namereg inside of the add command? If so, I can't do it cuz I have other variables ex: ```cbreg = None #more
bdreg = None
descreg = None
libreg = None
invreg = None
btreg = None
ssreg = None
slugreg = None```, and I wanted it to have spaces in each arguments.

Comment: No, I mean that the name of the variable you choose to store the value should be different from the name of the function you use to implement the command.

Comment: Can you modify the full script (or a part of it)? I don't really get it. Thanks.

Comment: ?..............................................................